# How to redirect standard Mac OS X log output that my app is generating to a file?

Tags: c++, macos, logging

I have a C++ application. One of the libraries it uses generates this kind of messages, it's visible in the output of my app: `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104bdee90`

How can I hook up to this log stream and get this message from within my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `pipe()` within your program, and then use `dup2()` to set STDOUT_FILENO to be a copy of the write side of that pipe.  Then your app could `read()` from the pipe (and perhaps `select()` on it).

Or, you could see if there's some option for that library to provide a user-defined logging hook that you can get more direct callbacks via.